# My browser app keeps crashing in iPad simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, crash

My app keeps crashing in the iPad simulator. I have searched and nothing has worked. It opens, you see a black screen and it crashes. Xcode displays no warning. Can you see if there is something wrong with my code that is causing this? http://www.mediafire.com/?3qxbklixrxgv1kx#1

Comment: maybe post your source on pastbin instead?

Comment: Have you run the static analyser? Have you obtained a crash report?

Comment: Ew, MediaFire? Just post the code here instead...

Comment: Did you try reboot the device? Sometimes when I switch between release and debug builds, my iPhone just does not want to start the application, although it seems to lanuch, it just quits without starting any of my code after about 2 seconds.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I am using iPad simulator. Also I posted my whole project because it includes the whole app

Comment: @esqew Sorry you don't like mediafire

Comment: No warning? I see 19 warnings. 8 of them related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was just to synthesize your 'client' object in Ibrowse2ViewController.

i.e. replace the line #15 in Ibrowse2ViewController.m with this

@synthesize webView, addressBar, spinnerView, client;

Comment: I tried that. It still does not work. I have reported it here: http://www.mediafire.com/?l9iaxcnf4baav6v. I added the client and it still crashes.